# Tomcatのパスワードリセット方法

Tags: tomcat

現在、TomCatでサーバーを構築しようとしています。

以下の画面でManager Appを押すとパスワードが要求されましたが、そのパスワードがわかりません。どのようにリセットすればいいでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**出てきた画面：**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manager App ボタンの左隣にあるリンク **Manager Application How-To** の先に説明があります([Web版](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access))。

デフォルト状態で権限を持っているアカウントはありません。
`conf/tomcat-users.xml` に、例えば次の設定を追加する

```xml
<user username="craigmcc" password="secret" roles="manager-gui" />
```

と、ID: `craigmcc`, パスワード: `secret` でアクセスできるようになります。